# Android Custom Chooser Intent shows three options only

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display multiple options including that of camera, etc to end-user to pick (or click) a photo to set to a profile. Problem is, the chooser intent has multiple intents including google photos, one drive, files, etc but it's showing first three intents only.

Below is my code:

```
List < Intent > allIntents = new ArrayList < Intent > ();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    // Fetch all camera related intents
    Intent openCamera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    List < ResolveInfo > camList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(openCamera, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo: camList) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(openCamera);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        if (imageURI != null)
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageURI);

        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Fetch all gallery related intents
    Intent openGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    openGallery.setType("image/*");
    List < ResolveInfo > galList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(openGallery, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo: galList) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(openGallery);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    Intent deletePhoto = new Intent("com.my_package.intent.action.DELETE_PHOTO");
    List < ResolveInfo > delList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(deletePhoto, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo: delList) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(deletePhoto);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
        allIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Main intent
    Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);

    // Create a chooser
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source of the photo");
    // Add other intents now
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    return chooserIntent;
```

I have added intent-filter to my AndroidManifest.xml as well:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.my_package.intent.action.DELETE_PHOTO" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

The code works fine as expected in Android API 28 (ie. displays all the image related intents), but not in API 29+.

The chooserIntent does have extra values of multiple intents which are supposed to be displayed, it's just not displaying them.

Comment: Same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Zippy: It seems like the latest version(s) of Android supports upto 3 custom choosers only.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Intent.EXTRA_ALTERNATE_INTENTS
```

instead of

```
Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).